# Como eu posso resolver esse erro? Quero só dá <Text>{selectedValueEstado}</Text>

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, ecmascript-6

Como eu posso resolver esse erro?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele ocorre quando eu tento renderizar a *text* com `{selectedValueEstado}`.

Quando faço `<Text>{selectedValueCidade}</Text>` é tranquilo (sou novato, aí não tenho conhecimento disso).

**Estou usando esse *JSON* no *app*:**

```
{
  "sigla": "AC",
  "nome": "Acre",
  "cidades": [
    "Acrelândia",
    "Assis Brasil",
    "Brasiléia",
    "Bujari",
    "Capixaba",
    "Cruzeiro do Sul",
    "Epitaciolândia",
    "Feijó",
    "Jordão",
    "Mâncio Lima",
    "Manoel Urbano",
    "Marechal Thaumaturgo",
    "Plácido de Castro",
    "Porto Acre",
    "Porto Walter",
    "Rio Branco",
    "Rodrigues Alves",
    "Santa Rosa do Purus",
    "Sena Madureira",
    "Senador Guiomard",
    "Tarauacá",
    "Xapuri"
  ]
},
{
  "sigla": "AL",
  "nome": "Alagoas",
  "cidades": [
    "Água Branca",
    "Anadia",
    "Arapiraca",
    "Atalaia",
    "Barra de Santo Antônio",
    "Barra de São Miguel",
    "Batalha",
    "Belém",
    "Belo Monte",
    "Boca da Mata",
    "Branquinha",
    "Cacimbinhas",
    "Cajueiro",
    "Campestre",
[...]
```

**Esse é o *picker* Estado:**

```
export default props => (
  <View>
    {
      props.data ?
      <Picker selectedValue={props.selectedValue} onValueChange={props.onValueChange}>
        {
          props.data.map(estado =>
            <Picker.Item key={estado} label={estado.nome} value={estado} />)
        }
      </Picker>
      :
      null
    }
  </View>
)
```

**Esse é o *picker* Cidade:**

```
export default props => (
   <View>
    {
      props.data ?
      <Picker selectedValue={props.selectedValue} onValueChange={props.onValueChange}>
        {
          props.data.cidades.map(cidade =>
            <Picker.Item key={cidade} label={cidade} value={cidade} />)
        }
      </Picker>
      :
      <Picker selectedValue={props.selectedValue} onValueChange={props.onValueChange}>
        <Picker.Item label={'Selecione'} />
      </Picker>
    }
  </View>
)
```

**O render está assim:**

```
render() {
  const { selectedValueCidade, selectedValueEstado, uf } = this.state;

  return (

    <Text style={Estilos.texto}>ONDE VOCÊ MORA?</Text>

    <View style={Estilos.picker1}>
      <SelectEstados
        selectedValue={selectedValueEstado}
        data={uf}
        onValueChange={this.renderValueChangeEstado}
      />
    </View>

    <View style={Estilos.picker2}>
      <SelectCidades
        selectedValue={selectedValueCidade}
        data={selectedValueEstado}
        onValueChange={this.renderValueChangeCidade}
      />
    </View>

    <Text>{selectedValueEstado}</Text>
    <Text>{selectedValueCidade}</Text>
```

O problema é quando tento rodar esse `<Text>{selectedValueEstado}</Text>`.

Comment: Agora tá postado certinho

Comment: A estrutura do objeto selectedValueEstado é esse json que você postou? Olhando seu codigo o problema que você esta tentando renderizar um objeto e isso é ilegal você tem que mapear as chaves dele, com `{JSON.stringify(objeto)}` ele mostra o conteudo, mas um objeto puro o dom nao compreende, por isso a mensagem de erro.

Comment: O que dá quando fazes `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.selectedValueEstado));`? Podes dar um exemplo do que pensas que `<Text>{selectedValueEstado}</Text>` pode mostrar?

Comment: Isso, a estrutura do selectedValueEstado é o json. Eu to querendo da um text do nome do estado, exemplo: "nome": "Acre", Ai o Text = Acre.

Comment: Eu consigo dá o Text de {selectedValueCidade}, mas o {selectedValueEstado} é como o JustCase falou, ele é um objeto, como eu faria isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa ! Como ele é um JSON ou você da um map ou então um JSON stringfy na posição que deseja, ou nele inteiro.

Exemplos:

```
<Text> {JSON.stringify(selectedValueEstado)} </Text>

{
    selectedValueEstado.map((uf) =>
        <Text key={uf.nome}> uf.nome </Text>
   ))
}
```